# Illegal type conversion required in MPI, advice on debugging?

Tags: c, casting, mpi

I am using MPI_Bcast in C, when I complied the model, it gives the error 
    PGC-S-0094-Illegal type conversion required (om3coupled.c: 7284)

but line 7284 is a pretty simple code:

```
MPI_Bcast(sumw,1,MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

where sumw is a float value size of 1, I defined it earlier. I tried to broadcast it from the root process to all nodes.
I know I probably messed up somewhere else to result in error in this seemingly correct line, but I got only error message on this line. Does anyone have any idea how to debug ? Since the code is 7000+ lines, so I did not attach the original code

Answer (score 1):

prototype is:

```
int MPI_Bcast( void *buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int root, 
           MPI_Comm comm )
```

you have to pass the *address* of your float like if it were an array of 1 element:

```
MPI_Bcast(&sumw,1,MPI_FLOAT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: You are right, it is indeed the address issue. My confusion is that I saw lots of MP_Bcast in the model just passing the float matrix without adding "&", such as        MPI_Bcast(ind,nmem,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);                      where ind is a float type one dimensional array (1*nmem). When is "&" necessary?

Comment: you need `&` to convert to address when you have values. If you have an array, you don't need it since it's already an address.